# Recursive method not working correctly using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am writing a basic boggle program. My recursive method is as follows:

```
function findWords(str, i, j) {

  if (j<0 || i<0 || i>=4 || j>=4)
      return;

  if (marked[i][j])
      return;

  marked[i][j] = true;
  str = str+Board[i][j];
  document.write(str + " ");

  if(str.length>4)
      return;

  if(isWord(str)==true)
      document.write(str);

  for (var ii = -1; ii<=1; ii++)
      for (var jj = -1; jj<=1; jj++)
          findWords(str, i+ii, j+jj);
          marked[i][j] = false;
}
```

However it only goes through one time. It stops at 
"if(isWord(str)==true)
 document.write(str);". When I comment out this portion of the code, the method works almost as expected. Is there a reason that the program would just stop at this point? Any advice is appreciated guys.

Comment: Is this function being called while the page is loading, or after?

Comment: Well, what is `isWord`? Is there an error in the JavaScript console? Why are you writing `==true`?

Comment: it is being called as the page is loading

Comment: isWord works in other parts of the program, it just determines if the word is a valid 3 letter word by looking at a list i put into the code.

Comment: What I mean is, do you know that the program is breaking at `if(...) document.write(...)` and not inside the `isWord`? If you do know, how do you know? If you know by an error message, the error message should be included in the question. "Works in other parts of the program" is not a proof in anything other than Haskell, due to global state and side effects.

Comment: mm to check the page loading issue change the document.write to console.log.. im curious if this is the issue

Comment: thanks for the help guys. I made the rookie mistake and misspelled a function name. Everything works for the most part. However, the recursive method is not fully traversing the 4x4 grid. It only seems to pick up on a few words, and not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing some brackets in there as follows:

```
function findWords(str, i, j){

    if(j<0 || i<0 || i>=4 || j>=4) return;

    if (marked[i][j]) return;

    marked[i][j] = true;
    str = str+Board[i][j];
    document.write(str + " ");

    if(str.length>4) return;

    if(isWord(str)==true)
    {
       document.write(str);
    }

    for(var ii = -1; ii<=1; ii++)
    {
        for (var jj = -1; jj<=1; jj++)
        {
            findWords(str, i+ii, j+jj);
        }
    }
    marked[i][j] = false;
}
```